# jquery datatables question

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

***EDIT*
Nevermind...  I really was missing the obvious... duh.**

I have a five-column table and am using jquery.datatables.js (http://www.datatables.net/). I'm trying to figure out how to remove sorting for the first and fifth columns so that it's not an option at all...

I've tried the function below, but it's still adding a sort to the columns:

```
$('#searchlist').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                    { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },
                    { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },
                    null
                ]
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you answered your own question, you should post the answer below so that others can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use aoColumnDefs.

```
$('#searchlist').dataTable({
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"bSortable":false, 'aTargets': [0, 4]},
            {"bSortable":true, "asSorting": [ "asc" ], 'aTargets': [1]},
            {"bSortable":true,"asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ], 'aTargets': [2, 3] },
      ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use "bSortable": false

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchlist').dataTable({
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aoColumns": [
                {"bSortable":false},
                {"bSortable":true, "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
                {"bSortable":true,"asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },
                {"bSortable":true, "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },
                {"bSortable":false}
            ]
});
```